# Spanning tree with disconnecting set

Tags: graph-theory

How do i approach this problem?

Assume $G$ is a connected graph and $e_1$ and $e_2$ are its edges such that every spanning tree of $G$ contains at least one of them. Prove that $\left\{e_1,e_2\right\}$ form a disconnecting set for $G$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that they are not a disconnecting set for $G$ and remove them to create the connected graph $G'$.  Take a spanning tree for $G'$ and show that this gives a spanning tree for $G$, contradicting the hypothesis that such a tree should contain one of those edges.

Comment: For taking a spanning tree for $G'$ and showing that this gives a spanning tree for $G$, how do i show that? in proof

Comment: A spanning tree is a subgraph that satisfies some extra conditions.  Since $G'$ is a subgraph of $G$ every subgraph of $G'$ is a subgraph of $G$.  So a spanning tree for $G'$ is a subgraph of $G$.  What are the extra conditions that a spanning tree must satisfy?  Are those conditions affected by adding more edges to the graph?

Comment: Spanning tree must contain all the vertices, also adding more edges wont affect the conditions on graph. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, use those facts to show that a spanning tree for $G'$ is a spanning tree for $G$.